# space is a vacuum there is no drag, so would hydrogen harvesting from space to use as fuel be possible once in orbit?

Tags: design-alternative, interplanetary, travel

If space is a vacuum and there is no drag, would hydrogen harvesting from space to use as fuel be possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "there is no drag" seems incompatible with ramming a scoop through the atmosphere. Or if it's a vacuum, there's nothing to scoop. Probably gonna have to pick one.

Comment: If space is a vacuum and there is no drag, there would not be any hydrogen to harvest.

Comment: I don't see what drag has to do with it. You wouldn't really be collecting hydrogen by means of a physical scoop anyway... you'd probably be using a magnetic field to pull it in.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym It doesn't matter if you have a physical scoop or not. Magnets don't circumvent Newton's third law.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym You should see that hydrogen is not pulled by a magnetic field.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I'm aware that "scooping" hydrogen requires a momentum transfer. The question says "space is a vacuum and there's no drag" and I'm trying to understand what drag has to do with anything in the context of capturing tenuous gas.

Comment: @Uwe The solar wind and interstellar medium are largely made up of hydrogen ions, that is to say single protons without an accompanying electron, which makes it magnetically active. The Bussard ramjet concept uses a magnetic field to capture hydrogen ions for fuel, and the earth's magnetic field redirects solar wind particles.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym And the answer is that capturing gas, no matter how tenuous, no matter how it's captured, will involve drag. Whether a physical scoop is used is irrelevant. The issue is that the premise of the question is false: space is not a perfect vacuum, there is non-zero drag, and the drag will be more or less proportional to the amount of hydrogen available to be collected.

Comment: Densities in space vary quite a bit. Low orbits incur higher drag than higher orbits (and this require more station-keeping). Interplanetary space has even less density, as should interstellar space (but we have limited experience of that)

Comment: @DarthPseudonym The earth's magnetic field captures ions in the Van Allen Belts but these belts are huge. To capture ions in a much smaller area a much stronger magnetic field is needed.

Comment: @Uwe Sorry, did you just say "hydrogen is not pulled by a magnetic field, so you need a really *big* magnetic field to move it"? In any case, yes, the Van Allen belts are huge, but the earth's magnetic field is also extremely weak. Yes, a bussard scoop would require a huge magnetic field, but that's a wildly different statement than "hydrogen is not pulled by a magnetic field".

Answer (score 5):

Space is ***almost*** a vacuum.

...except for the small traces of for example hydrogen.

The little of it there is provides drag, as would hitting anything else. By harvesting it, you're slowing your spacecraft.

That said, you could in theory absolutely collect some hydrogen and then use it as propellant, provided you eject it at a higher speed than you slowed it down when collecting it. This is a little tricky though, as for example burning hydrogen with oxygen produces exhaust at "only" 4.5km/s, compared to the 8km/s you are orbitin at in low Earth orbit. A net loss for the chemical option. By electric propulsion (or [fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bussard_ramjet)) you could get a fast enough exhaust, but no practical implementations of this exist.

Comment: ... but ESA have an ion engine for accelerating the trace atmosphere at VLEO

Comment: @JCRM that works because they don’t “collect” the gas molecules.  They let them pass through the engine and use EM forces to accelerate them further.  There is no (or less) momentum loss to the craft from the ingested propellant.  A combustion engine could theoretically  work if you didnt slow the ingested hydrogen to “zero” velocity, like a space jet engine.  Combusting it at the speeds youd have to maintain though is probably impossible.

Comment: Spacecraft can absolutely go faster than their exhaust velocity.  Better rethink that part. https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30056/6944

Comment: @OrganicMarble *rockets* can do so.

Comment: @OrganicMarble if I understand the answer correctly, it’s saying that if the exhaust velocity is lower than the relative velocity between the spacecraft and the incoming hydrogen, it will have a net loss in momentum. The orbital velocity is relevant since that’s the approximate relative velocity between the incoming gas and the spacecraft. It’s not saying that a normal rocket carrying its own fuel couldn’t go faster than the exit velocity, just that if velocity out < velocity in, the craft will lose momentum

Comment: @OrganicMarble This seems to be a knee-jerk reaction, and not what's going on here. There's a significant difference between carrying your propellant and slowing it down from the medium around you.